# Showing an element with an if statement in nextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to add a parameter to a nextJS components which only show if a condition is true.
Currently, I'm returning this:

```js
        return (
            <div role="main" aria-label={this.props.title} className={Styles.main + " " + color}>
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                <h2>{this.props.sub}</h2>
                <div className={Styles.buttons}>
                    <a className={Styles.button} href="#features">Features</a>
                    <a className={Styles.button} href="#commands">Commands</a>
                    <a className={Styles.button} href={this.props.inviteURL}>Invite</a>
                    {() => {
                        if (1==1) {
                            return (
                                <a className={Styles.button} href={this.props.sourceURL}>Source</a>
                            )
                        }
                    }}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
```

Currently, it shows the top bit of the return and the buttons inside of that, but the one with the text `Source` isn't shown.
Why isn't it showing, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a function that is never executed, so the component will never appear, it also expects an expression, so if you use simple `if` statements it won't work, as the following:

```js
 return (
            <div role="main" aria-label={this.props.title} className={Styles.main + " " + color}>
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                <h2>{this.props.sub}</h2>
                <div className={Styles.buttons}>
                    <a className={Styles.button} href="#features">Features</a>
                    <a className={Styles.button} href="#commands">Commands</a>
                    <a className={Styles.button} href={this.props.inviteURL}>Invite</a>
                    {if(1==1) {
                            return (
                                <a className={Styles.button} href={this.props.sourceURL}>Source</a>
                            )
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
```

I would suggest using ternary operators or `&&` instead of an `if` which leaves you the following solution:

```js
 return (
            <div role="main" aria-label={this.props.title} className={Styles.main + " " + color}>
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                <h2>{this.props.sub}</h2>
                <div className={Styles.buttons}>
                    <a className={Styles.button} href="#features">Features</a>
                    <a className={Styles.button} href="#commands">Commands</a>
                    <a className={Styles.button} href={this.props.inviteURL}>Invite</a>
                    {1==1 && <a className={Styles.button} href={this.props.sourceURL}>Source</a>}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
```

Comment: The first one gave a syntax error, but the second worked fine, thanks